# python - how to find area under curve?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

would like to ask if it is possible to calculate the area under curve for a fitted distribution curve?

The curve would look like this

[image]

I've seen some post online regarding the usage of trapz, but i'm not sure if it will work for a curve like that. Please enlighten me and thank you for the help!

Comment: what is your input? function or set of points?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320262/calculating-the-area-under-a-curve-given-a-set-of-coordinates-without-knowing-t    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238489/python-integrating-area-under-curve-with-uneven-steps-in-x    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814353/using-scipy-to-perform-discrete-integration-of-the-sample

Comment: It's math stuff, just integrate the function.

Comment: Please give the (minimal) code you have so far.

Comment: I'd guess the sum is exactly 1 and the answer to your question is yes.

Answer (score 7):

If your distribution, `f`, is discretized on a set of points, `x`, that you know about, then you can use `scipy.integrate.trapz` or `scipy.integrate.simps` directly (pass `f`, `x` as arguments in that order). For a quick check (e.g. that your distribution is normalized), just sum the values of `f` and multiply by the grid spacing:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import trapz, simps

x, dx = np.linspace(-100, 250, 50, retstep=True)
mean, sigma = 90, 20
f = np.exp(-((x-mean)/sigma)**2/2) / sigma / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)
print('{:18.16f}'.format(np.sum(f)*dx))
print('{:18.16f}'.format(trapz(f, x)))
print('{:18.16f}'.format(simps(f, x)))
```

Output:

```
1.0000000000000002
0.9999999999999992
1.0000000000000016
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to find a function from a graph. You can check [here](http://www.intmath.com/blog/mathematics/how-to-find-the-equation-of-a-quadratic-function-from-its-graph-6070). Then you can use integration in python with scipy. You can check [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html) for integration.
It is just math stuff as Daniel Sanchez says.